# Update all instances of an object in entire database

Tags: mongodb

Im new to Mongodb and have a begginer question: if i had a document named Product and within it i had an object

```
{
  id: 1
  name: Motorcycle
}
```

And i had another document named User with favorites that include said products

```
{
  id: 1
  name: User1
  favorites: [
    {
      id: 1
      name: Motorcycle
    }
  ]
}
```

Assuming a thousand users had the same favorite product, how should I try to update the name of the product? i want to do this with pure mongodb and without using something like mongoose

edit: i would like the update to reflect on all Motorcycle products within all of the User objects

Comment: what is your mongodb version?

Comment: db version: v3.4.9

Comment: If you have separate model for **Product** then you can update it directly like `Product.update()` and can save its `_id` to the **User** `favorites` array

Comment: You should not have duplicates like that in your database. Store the product once and reference it from the user with a unique ID.

Comment: @RaphaelEstrada have you tried my solution?